# Проблема с кодировкой в microsoft.office.interop.word

Tags: c#, кодировка, ms-word

Добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Встретился с такой задачей: на C# автозаполнение шаблона `*.dot` из `*.csv`, изваял следующий код:

```
try  { parametrs = File.ReadAllLines(fail_istok); // читаем файл *.csv построчно в массив string  
for (int i = 0; i < parametrs.Length; i++) //каждую строку обрабатываем отдельно  
            {  
             str_link = parametrs[i].Split(';'); // рЕжим сепаратором строки  
             Word._Application oWord = new Word.Application(); // создаем приложение word  
             Word._Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(fail_accept); // берем шаблон  
//MessageBox.Show( Encoding.Default.CodePage.ToString());// посмотреть какая кодировочная страница **(1)**
for (int s = 0; s < str_link.Length; s++)    
{  
oDoc.Bookmarks[textBox_nameper.Text.ToString() + s].Range.Text = str_link[s]; //вставляем текст строки в шаблон в закладку.  
}    
oDoc.SaveAs(FileName: dir_save + "\\"+ textBox_namedoc.Text.ToString() + i + ".docx"); //Путь к заполненному документу  
                            oDoc.Close(); //закрываем шаблон Word  
                            oDoc = null;  
                            oWord.Quit();//Закрываем приложение Word  
                            oWord = null;                                  
            }   
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность входных данных","Ошибка программы", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);  
        }  
            MessageBox.Show("Готово, обработано: "+ progressBar1.Value+ " файла(ов) ... ");
```

Все, вроде, нормально работает и вставляется, но корректно отображается только латиница, кириллица заполняется ромбами с вопросительными знаками. Не подходит кодировка, на компе стоит chcp >> cp-866, а здесь **(1)** показывает cp-1251, пробовал вставку из текстового файла с UNicod-ом, кириллица вставляется четко, но в рукопашную переводить исходные файлы в unicod каждый раз тяжко.
Как их привести к одному знаменателю и сделать нормально функционирующую прогу?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
File.ReadAllLines(fail_istok)
```

на

```
File.ReadAllLines(fail_istok, new System.Text.Encoding(866))
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Ларчик просто открывался:
     File.ReadAllLines(fail_istok, Encoding.Default);